# How it can execute classes in swift without instance?

Tags: swift, class, instance, execute

I am new to swift and there is something that i couldn't understand and it is about classes execute.
I thought  that class can't execute them self , you need to define an instance variable to work with the class's methods and properties  but i noticed in xcode files that the classes don't have in instance variable why is that? and how the class get executed itself without an instance  ?

Thanks advance

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var theView: UIView = UIView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    }

}
/// Why i donl't need this line of code to worke with the class above
/// instead the class above execute itself without this instance
var theViewControllerInstance = ViewController()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a ViewController instance and do all the work by your self, but a more commonly way is to bind this class in interface builder (storyboard or xib), when app start and load UI resource, the instance is created for you.

Answer (score 4):

Normally you would create an instance of a class to execute a function, but if you wish to; you can make a class function:

```
class MyClass {
    class func myClassMethod() {
        print("This is printed from a class function")
    }

    func myInstanceMethod() {
        print("This is printed from a normal function")
    }
}
```

You use a class function in the following way:

```
MyClass.myClassMethod()
```

And a standard function like this:

```
let myInstance = MyClass()
myInstance.myInstanceMethod()
```